# Render blade view from URL path

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've an unusual and interesting problem that I am trying to solve.

We had to put some of our blade views to S3 storage and render them from S3 url with passed variables.

For example:

```
view('page.user.show', ['user' => User::first()])->render();
```

Now, since we have our **page.user.show** blade file stored in S3 storage on the path "*/views/pages/user/show.blade.php*"

We somehow need to make Laravel get that view from **s3 URL path** instead from ***resource_path***

So we need something like this:

```
view('s3url.com/views/pages/user/show.blade.php', ['user' => User::first()])->render();
```

Is there any way we can do this in Laravel ? Or, at least read content of blade file from S3 path and render that string content with variables?

Comment: You can't pass variable to s3 storage. You will need to get file contents first, then store it in `temp` folder in local. Then you can pass variable, get desired file and delete file from `temp` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Downloading file isn't a option. Is there any way I can do that by reading content only and then passing variables to that string content, and render ? Without downloading file in temp folder.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: Create your custom directory views in S3 and create a symbolic link inside the views directory and access it with the regular syntax.

Comment: Could you use `$view = View::make(file_get_contents($path_to_s3))->with($viewdata);` and then `return $view;`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this, you'll need to implement a custom version of the Laravel `Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface`. Your best bet is to create a new view finder that can load blade templates from S3 and move them to the local filesystem temporarily.

You can probably just extend the `FileViewFinder` class, and add some custom logic to the `find()` method. In there, try something like:

```php
if (Str::startsWith($name, 's3::')) {
  // This gets a temp file that PHP will clean up for you
  $name = stream_get_meta_data(tmpfile())['uri'];

  // Download the Blade template from S3 and store it temporarily
  file_put_contents($name, Storage::disk('s3')->get(Str::after($name, 's3::')));

  // Return the path
  return $name;
}
```

Then you'll need to swap in your new finder using `View::setFinder`.

The major downside of this approach is that you'll need to download views from S3 every time you render them. You probably want to at least add some caching to the system so that you're not hitting S3 every time a page loads.